# Why do i got this error of index=0 and lenght = 0 from the main class?

Tags: java, arrays

I got this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
>       at RecursiveSquares.main(RecursiveSquares.java:40)

```java
public static void draw(int n, double x, double y, double size) {
        if (n == 0) return;

        drawSquare( x, y, size);

        // 2.2 ratio looks good
        double ratio = 2.2;

        // recursively draw 4 smaller trees of order n-1
        draw(n-1, x - size/2, y - size/2, size/ratio);    // lower left  
        draw(n-1, x - size/2, y + size/2, size/ratio);    // upper left  
        draw(n-1, x + size/2, y - size/2, size/ratio);    // lower right 
        draw(n-1, x + size/2, y + size/2, size/ratio);    // upper right
    }


    // read in an integer command-line argument n and plot an order n recursive
    // squares pattern
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double x = 0.5, y = 0.5;   // center of square
        double size = 0.5;         // side length of square
        draw(n, x, y, size);
```

Comment: It looks like you have no arguments specified when you start the application, so args[0] will fail.

Comment: index 0 means the index of the first element. length 0 means there are no elements in your array. You are trying to get the first element of an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the values of `args` array when executing the program. For eg.

`java RecursiveSquares 10`